# The Chinese language on loadrunner's playback log shows the mess

Tags: loadrunner

The Chinese language on loadrunner's playback log shows the mess。

loadrunner version ：12.53；

How do I set it？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWhu4.png)

Comment: What is the problem? It all looks like Chinese to me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue? Do you want to correlate that value?

Comment: @Buzzy A Japanese.